# rds.extensions parameter is not available on RDS for Postgres 16

Tags: amazon-rds, postgresql-16

We're working towards upgrading our database to postgres 16, part of the work is to create new AWS param group. When i'm comparing current prod param group with new param group I see that `rds.extensions` parameter is not available.

There is an available `rds.allowed_extensions` parameter, but as far as I understand it's different.

Are all extensions that were set with older version of postgres are just turned on by default now? Or it's different?

I tried to change this param with terraform:

```
│ Error: modifying DB Parameter Group (****): InvalidParameterValue: Could not find parameter with name: rds.extensions
│       status code: 400
```

I also tried to find this parameter in AWS console but it's not visible